# Display data from two fields from different tables (related by a Foreign Key) on a single row in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, row

I am developing a Time 'Punching' System, and I'm trying to build a table in PHP to show data horizontally from 2 tables:

tb_users AS u

tb_punch AS p

I'd like data to be shown like this:

```
 u.user   p.punch    p.punch    p.punch    p.punch
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|User 1 | 10:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 19:00:00 |
|User 2 | 08:00:00 | 12:00:00 |          |          |
|User 3 | 09:00:00 |          |          |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

And so on...

But I'm getting the following result instead:

```
 u.user   p.punch    p.punch    p.punch    p.punch   p.punch    p.punch    p.punch
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|User 1 | 10:00:00 |          |          |          |         |          |         |
|User 1 | 10:00:00 | 12:00:00 |          |          |         |          |         |
|User 1 | 10:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 |          |         |          |         |
|User 1 | 10:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 19:00:00 |         |          |         |
|User 2 | 10:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 19:00:00 |08:00:00 |          |         |
|User 2 | 10:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 19:00:00 |08:00:00 | 12:00:00 |         |
|User 3 | 10:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 19:00:00 |08:00:00 | 12:00:00 |09:00:00 |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

I mean, it repeats every PUNCH each line, when all I wanted as to group punchs by user.

Here is how I am trying to do this:

```
$query = "SELECT u.user, p.punch FROM users u INNER JOIN punches p ON u.id = p.id_user"
$rt = pg_query($query) or die ("Error: [" . $query . "]");

$punches = array();
echo "<tbody>";
while($nt=pg_fetch_assoc($rt)){

    echo "<tr>";

    echo    "<td>" . $nt[user] . "</td>";

    $punches[] = $nt[punch]; 
    foreach ($punches as $punch){
        echo    "<td>" . date('H:i:s',strtotime($punch)) . "</td>";
    }
}
echo "</tr></tbody>";
?>
</table>
```

Any clues on what might be wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: That doesn't seem possible, unless I'm missing something. Your select statement only has two columns, but both of your results show more than that...

Answer (score 1):

I do not advise you to mix SQL queries with presentation layer nor workflow layer. Using Pomm would allow you to query the database like the following:

```
SELECT 
 u.user,
 ... -- other users fields
 array_agg(p.punch) AS punch_times 
FROM 
 users u 
   INNER JOIN punchs p ON u.id = p.id_user
GROUP BY
  u.user,
  ... -- other users fields
```

And get directly a collection of Users object hydrated with an extra array of DateTime in a field named `punch_times`. So your template would become:

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $user['user'] ?></td>
    <td>
      <ul>
      <?php foreach ($user['punch-times'] as $punch_time): ?>
        <li><?php echo $punch_time->format('H:i:s') ?></li>
      <?php endforeach ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `GROUP BY u.id` to your query.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but would need also user in group by or aggregate expression of user (whatever suits the OP best — I've just grouped by the field he's looking for for simplicity).

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT u.user, string_agg(p.punch,',') AS punches FROM users AS u JOIN punches AS p ON u.id=p.id_user GROUP BY u.user`.

And then something like

```
while($nt = pg_fetch_assoc($rt)) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$nt['user']}</td>";
    echo "<td>",implode('</td><td>',explode(',',$nt['punches'])),"</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

P.S. also, your code seems to yield unbalanced `<tr>`/`</tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with a little help of a friend of mine I figured it out.

I didn't change the query statement, just flagged out some TRs and TDs to be shown under certain conditions. Here's what I've done:

```
echo "<tbody>";
$prev_user = "";
$flag = true;

while($nt=pg_fetch_assoc($rt)){

    if ($flag) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $nt[user] . "</td>";
        $prev_user = $nt[user];
    }

    if ($prev_user != $nt[user]) {
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $nt[user] . "</td>";
    }

    echo "<td>" . date('H:i:s',strtotime($nt[punch])) . "</td>";

    $prev_user = $nt[user];

    $flag = false;

}

echo "</tbody>";
```

This solved my problem and now I'm getting the table like this:

```
u.user   p.punch    p.punch    p.punch    p.punch
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|User 1 | 10:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 19:00:00 |
|User 2 | 08:00:00 | 12:00:00 |          |          |
|User 3 | 09:00:00 |          |          |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```